# sort dropdownlist by date, after it is populated from datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to sort the dropdownlist by date, but i cant figure out how.

```
ddate.DataSource = myTable


    ddate.DataTextField = "ddate7"
    ddate.DataValueField = "ddate7"
    ddate.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If myTable is a `DataTable` then you could put it into a Dataview and sort it there like this:

```
Dim dv As New DataView(myTable)
dv.Sort = "ddate7"

ddate.DataSource = dv
ddate.DataTextField = "ddate7"
ddate.DataValueField = "ddate7"
ddate.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DataView to sort and filter the DataTable you may try the following code,

```
DataView dv = new DataView(myTable);
dv.Sort = "ddate7 ASC";
ddate.DataSource = dv;
ddate.DataTextField = "ddate7";
ddate.DataValueField = "ddate7";
ddate.DataBind();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry this is C# code I think you just need to remove those semicolons to work with vb.net

Comment: @zeroef, thanks. I think I also forgot about the Dim thing :)